# RxJS filtering over multiple streams

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

Actually I stuck in this problem.

I have a stream for events using Angularfire2.

```js
this.events$ = this.af.database.list('/events')
    .map(events => {
    const filtered = events.filter(event => event.title === "Title 1");
    return filtered;
    });
```

which retrieves me data like this:

```js
{
  title: "Title 1",
  userid: "1"  
}
```

Then I have a second stream for the user like this:

```js
this.users$ = this.af.database.list('/users/1')
    .map(users => {
    const filtered = users.filter(user => user.name === "Name 1");
        return filtered;
    });
```

Now I want to combine the streams to get the following result:

Return me all the events where `event.title === "Title 1"` and `user.name === "Name 1"`

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This answer is outdated! Unfortunately, I can't delete it.**

Something like this works for me:

```
this.events$ = this.af.database.list('/events')
      .map(events => {
        events.map(event => {
            this.af.database.object('users/' + event.userid)

            .subscribe(user => {
                event.user = user;
              })
            })
             
            const filtered = events.filter(event => event.title === "Test 1")
                .filter(event => event.user.name === "Name 1");;
                return filtered;
        });
```

I'm subscribing to the users inside my Event observable. After that I save the user to a property of my event.

Work's fine for me!

Notice: If you want to get real time updates of your user, save the observable to the property and not the user object. <then subscribe to it later in the view.

Comment: As soon as your calling `subscribe` inside an observable you've gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge two Observables use [`merge()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-merge):

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7j71Qzok7CoFVt49QBs4

```
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';

let stream1 = new Subject();
let stream2 = new Subject();

Observable.merge(stream1, stream2)
  .subscribe(r => {
    console.log(r);
  });

stream1.next(43);
stream2.next(42);
stream1.next(41);
```

Prints to console:

```
43
42
41
```

If you want to emit a single value after all Observables complete use [`forkJoin()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin):

```
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';

let stream1 = new Subject();
let stream2 = new Subject();

Observable.forkJoin(stream1, stream2)
  .subscribe(r => {
    console.log(r);
  });

stream1.next(43);
stream2.next(42);
stream1.next(41);

stream1.complete();
stream2.complete();
```

Prints to console:

```
[41, 42]
```

Comment: THX for the answer